# n agents accessing a resource

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes

I want to solve a simple stochastic problem. Imagine there are n agents who want to access a resource, with a probability p at a given time t. What ist the probability that the resource will be free and not accessed by an agent. How does the result change with 2n and 2 available resources?
How do i solve this problem?

Comment: Could you walk us through a simple example for the case of n=2, i.e. 2 agents with 1 resource, and 4 agents with 2 resources?

Comment: Huh ok, pfff let's imagin you have 2 roomates and a video game console, you know that the other two players want to play a video game with the probability of 0.1 at a time t (for the porpose of the problem, let's assume that only one person can play at a time). So what is the probability that you can play at time t. The 2n is obvious. Now you have 5 roommates and 2 consoles. What's the probability of accessing any one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resource will be free with probability $(1-p)^n$.

When there are $2n$ agents and $2$ resources, one of the resources will be free with probability $(1-p)^{2n} + 2np(1-p)^{2n-1}$.

In general, you want to calculate the tail of a Binomial distribution. When $p = c/n$ and $n$ is large, the distribution is approximately Poisson.